# COMException: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients Visual Studio vbnet

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I wrote a program in VB.net in visual studio and wanted to test if it still works, after installing windows 11
now I have the problem it always stops at the line `Dim ws As Worksheet = wk2.Sheets(1)` Does anyone know the problem?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim MyExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        MyExcel.Visible = True
        Dim wk1, wk2 As Workbook

        Dim path1, path2, path3 As String
        path1 
        path2 
        path3 
        wk1 = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(path1)
        wk2 = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(path2)
        ' Dim ws1 = wk1.Sheets(1)
        'ws1.Range("F:F").Replace(("_*"), "")


        wk1.Unprotect()
        wk2.Unprotect()

        Dim Row1 = wk1.Sheets(1).Cells(wk1.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row
        Dim Row2 = wk2.Sheets(1).Cells(wk2.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row + 1
        Dim Rng1 = MyExcel.Intersect(wk1.Sheets(1).UsedRange, wk1.Sheets(1).Range("2:" & Row1))
        Dim Rng2 = wk2.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Row2).ReSize(Rng1.Rows.Count, Rng1.Columns.Count)
        Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value
        wk1.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        wk2.SaveAs(path3)
        wk2.Close()


        Dim ws As Worksheet = wk2.Sheets(1)


        Dim StartDatum As String
        Dim EndDatum As String
        StartDatum = InputBox("Start-Datum:", "Eingabe", Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD"))
        EndDatum = InputBox("End-Datum:", "Eingabe", Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD"))

        ws.Range("D:D").Replace(("Startdatum im Format JJJJMMTT"), StartDatum)
        ws.Range("E:E").Replace(("Enddatum im Format JJJJMMTT"), EndDatum)
        ws.Range("A:AZ").Replace(("Keine Eintragung..."), "")
        ws.Range("A:AZ").Replace(("Keine Ei"), "")
        ws.Range("F:F").Replace(("_*"), "")
        ws.Range("F:F").Replace(("-*"), "") ' Bei Änderung nochmal hier löschen und mit dem oberen auskommentierten ersetzen.
        ws.Range("A:AZ").Replace(("Keine OP"), "")

        ws.SaveAs()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried it before and it worked. Now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I assume you are talking about VB.Net, not VBA or vbScript?!

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I edited the post.

Comment: You should set correct tags, else your question will not reach the persons that could possibly help you.

Comment: Haven't you just closed `wk2` when you're trying to get a Sheet from it?

Comment: `it always stops at the line` What exception did you get?